# Ember.js (1.0pre) property binding bug in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, ember.js

There seems to be a bug with the way that IE8 property bindings function in Ember 1.0pre.

Take the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/EdLk3/11/

When executed in Chrome, the fooView template displays:

```
view.fooView: hello
```

This is as expected, because the template outputs `{{view.foo}}`, and the view context gets `foo` from `fooBinding` which inherits `App.set('baz', "hello")`;

In IE8, however, the fooView template does not output any value from `{{view.foo}}`. What might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a IE8 bindAttr bug in Ember. It's been documented here.

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1300

It's been fixed now. Updating to the latest version of Ember fixed the issues I was having.